# Powershell script add email

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have a powershell script that I want to add a line or 2 that once the script completes it sends me an email with the results.

```
#Define Clustername
$clustername = "Cluster1"
 
#Get all clusterresources with the type Virtual machine
$clusterResource = Get-ClusterResource -Cluster $clustername | Where ResourceType -eq "Virtual Machine"
 
#Get VMSnapshots
Get-VM -ClusterObject $clusterResource | Get-VMSnapshot
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SMTP server setup [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.1) should work.